# Implementing text editor with seperate model and views in Java

Tags: java, swing, text, text-editor, jtextpane

I want to implement a text editor in java where the model and the view of the text area are completely seperate and some parts of the text are "calculated". I went through the documentation and some examples of the Java editor kit, Document and DocumentFilter, but I'm still lost on this subject.

In short what I want to do is a text editor where certain words matching a pattern (e.g.: ID123456) would be swapped with another property of the object referenced by the id in the matching text. This swap should only happen in the view though, when the text area is modified or saved then the original text should be saved not the one projected for the view. Of course in this case the projected text can't be changed, but this can easily be handled with a DocumentFilter.

An example to make the task clearer:

The model behind the text editor:

> Is it true that ID123 has the largest bauxite production of the world?
>
> No, it's not true, ID44 has the largest bauxite production.

What the user should see:

> Is it true that **Belgium** has the largest bauxite production of the world?
>
> No, it's not true, **Australia** has the largest bauxite production.

I'm currently thinking about writing a parser that does this conversion every time it's needed, but I don't really like this solution. Any help would be appreciated on what would be the optimal way to do this.

Comment: Are you looking for [`MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)?

Comment: `where the model and the view of the text area are completely seperate` Why do you need them separate? There are other ways of doing the replacements while keeping the 'raw' text intact outside of the Document (for instance DocumentFilter to replace into Document and keep raw (or delegate to a class that stores the raw))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to override EditorKit's read/write methods and add your own reader and writer (exact ones depend on EditorKit you extend).

On read place the IDs in an attribute of the character element e.g. MyCustomId=ID123 and store it in the model. Text of the element should be actually replaced with corresponding value (country in our case).

On write do opposite. Check whether text element has MyCustomId attribute specified. If the attribute exists write the value instead of the element text.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! I actually used your [tutorials](http://java-sl.com/editor_kit_tutorial.html) to help me with the implementation.
After the implementation I found RSyntaxTextArea though, which made it even easier, really handy tool.

Answer (score 0):

The model and the view **are** separated in JTextComponent. You have a Document which is the model, and Views that render the document. If you really insist on your approach, you should use a JTextPane backed with a [EditorKit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/EditorKit.html) where you replaced the ViewFactory by one of your own.

However, I would not recommend this approach. You don't want to change the way the document render. You just want to interpret some parts of the document before it is rendered. So what you need is a translator that translates `ID123` into `Belgium` when reading the document, and `Belgium` into `ID123` when writing.

To do so, you need to map your values in a Bi-directional Map ([this one for instance](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html)). Then, you need to override the `read` and `write` methods of your [EditorKit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/EditorKit.html)